# How to extract elements belong to the same tag name in web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[the web page being scraped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdvXL.png)

[the wrong output i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qwdw.png)

So basically I was trying to scrape over those rows of streamers on each page with the tag name "tr". And in each row, there's multiple columns that I want to include into my output. I was able to include almost all of those columns, but there's two that have the same tag name frustrated me a lot. (The two columns about followers) I tried the method of indexing them to get only odd or even, but the result is included in the second picture and it did not work out well. The numbers just keeps repeating itself and does not go down the way as it should. So is there some way to get the column of "followers gained" correctly into the output?

It's my first time asking here, so i am not sure if it is enough. I am glad to update more info later if needed.

```
for i in range(30):      # Number of pages plus one 
    url = "https://twitchtracker.com/channels/viewership?page={}&searchbox=Course+Name&searchbox_zip=ZIP&distance=50&price_range=0&course_type=both&has_events=0".format(i)
    headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
    
    channels = soup.find_all('tr')
    for idx, channel in enumerate(channels):
        if idx % 2 == 1:    
            idx += 1
        Name = ", ".join([p.get_text(strip=True) for p in channel.find_all('a', attrs={'style': 'color:inherit'})])
        Avg = ", ".join([p.get_text(strip=True) for p in channel.find_all('td', class_ = 'color-viewers')])
        Time = ", ".join([p.get_text(strip=True) for p in channel.find_all('td', class_ = 'color-streamed')])
        All = ", ".join([p.get_text(strip=True) for p in channel.find_all('td', class_ = 'color-viewersMax')])
        HW = ", ".join([p.get_text(strip=True) for p in channel.find_all('td', class_ = 'color-watched')])
        FG = ", ".join([soup.find_all('td', class_ = 'color-followers hidden-sm')[idx].get_text(strip=True)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Maybe an alternativ approach ?##

It uses `pandas` to read the tables, you just have to clean the ads out.

I also used `time.sleep()` delaying the loops and to be gentle to the server.

**Example**

```
import requests, time
import pandas as pd
df_list = []
for i in range(30):      # Number of pages plus one 
    url = "https://twitchtracker.com/channels/viewership?page={}&searchbox=Course+Name&searchbox_zip=ZIP&distance=50&price_range=0&course_type=both&has_events=0".format(i)
    headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    df_list.append(pd.read_html(page.text)[0])
    
    time.sleep(1.5)
    
df = pd.concat(df_list).reset_index(drop=True)
df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 2':'Name'}, inplace=True)
df.drop(df.columns[[0,1]],axis=1,inplace=True)
df[~df.Rank.str.contains(".ads { display:")].to_csv('table.csv', mode='w', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It actually works for me. It seems like I sticked with beautiful soup too much, and should try pandas as well. Thanks

Comment: There is not one right way, but sometimes one is shorter or easier to go. Have fun with `pandas`